# Save variable according to tableview statement into JSON file swift

Tags: swift, loops, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to change label text color in another viewcontroller according to if statement results in tableview controller, and for this I try to save help x value 0/1 into json file which I want to read in another view controller.
Simple JSON:

```
{
"x" : 1 or 0
}
```

I try to put function into tableview but I think it is not run.

Any suggestions?, thanks.

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
if a == b{

func save(){
guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "simple", withExtension: "json")
else {return}
let dictionary: [String: Int] = ["x":1]
do{
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options:[])
try data.write(to: fileUrl, options: [])
}catch{
print(error)
}

}else{

func save(){
guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "simple", withExtension: "json")
else {return}
let dictionary: [String: Int] = ["x":0]
do{
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options:[])
try data.write(to: fileUrl, options: [])
}catch{
print(error)
}
}
return cell
```

Comment: why are you using json file to do that?

Comment: i think you cannot write back to your bundle, you have to write to documents or cache directory.

Comment: what can I use for it? @Dilan Anuruddha

Comment: do you want to store values after app is close also, you can use user Defaults, or values need only when app close, you can use public dictionary or map

Comment: Do you have some manual or example for user defaults?